# Force.com Toolkit for .NET : Specify Fields to Update

Tags: c#, .net, force.com-toolkit-for-net

I don't want to update all fields on the object (Lead/Contact) I am updating, is there any way to avoid that?

I am trying to avoid having to pull all the fields from Salesforce just to update them again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to create new objects with just the fields you want to update.
You could either use strongly typed POCO or annonymous types.

E.g.

```
// annonymous types
var success = await client.UpdateAsync("Lead", lead.Id, new { Name = "Test Update" });
```

Comment: I used `dynamic c = new ExpandoObject();` but same principle.